# Any one know how to overcome "Compiler internal error. Process terminated with exit code 138" in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, intellij-idea, javac

It's a Java project where we are using Java 1.5.0 but I can't find a list of javac error codes anywhere. I've tried Invalidating the Cache and restarting. I've tried Rebuilding the Project. It's a maven project so I am able to compile from the Maven panel within IntelliJ but I need to run it as a Tomcat configuration which I don't know how to do outside of IntelliJ.

Edit: in IntelliJ, you can run your project via their Run/Debug Configurations. You can set up a configuration for an app, junit, tomcat etc... this is how I've been running my project to get the error

2nd Edit: It appears that my Java 1.5 was corrupt. When I removed it from intelliJ and then tried to add it back, IntelliJ told me that it was corrupt. Also I get bus errors at the command line...

```
$ ~/Java\ 1.5.0/Home/bin/javac -version
bus error
$ ~/Java\ 1.5.0/Home/bin/java -version
bus error
```

Comment: What do mean run it as Tomcat configuration? If you want to run it inside Tomcat in Maven outside of IntelliJ you can configure a Tomcat plugin into your build.xml and "mvn tomcat:run" http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

One option is to call `mvn package` to create the war file and deploy it manually to an already installed tomcat.

Another option is to use the [tomcat maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) and to call `mvn tomcat:run` This will run your application within an tomcat.